# What's the difference between "==" and "=~"?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given a string and a hash returned by `openssl`, why using `==` doesn't match them correctly but `=~` does?

Background question: [How can I force a script to use more resources?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119284/how-can-i-force-a-script-to-use-more-resources)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The binary operator, ‘=~’, has the same precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex3)). The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise. If the regular expression is syntactically incorrect, the conditional expression’s return value is 2.

From: [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

Hence your comparing for equality versus for a regular expression match.

Comment: (and beware that means substring match. The `b` regular expression is matched in `abc`, so `[[ abc =~ b ]]` is true, while for the fnmatch pattern matching operator (`[[ abc == b ]]`), it's not. The equivalent of `[[ abc =~ b ]]` is `[[ abc == *b* ]]`).